# C# Httpwebreqest will not generate a response unless Fiddler is running for specific host

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, httpwebrequest, x509certificate

There's actually an additional layer to this that if I try to access that host in my class's first request, it won't even work with Fiddler running.  I'm a bit baffled by it at the moment.

Here's code that works perfectly with Fiddler open:

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.ticketmaster.co.nz/member/order_history?start=10000");
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
        req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
        }
        req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.ticketmaster.com/member/addfavs?tm_link=tm_homeA_mytm_signin");
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
        req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
        }
```

However, if I close Fiddler and run in Debug mode in Visual Studio, I get the following Message:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

as well as the following Inner Exceptions:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

and

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Now, if I simply run the code below, I just get

> The operation has timed out

even if I have Fiddler open.

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.ticketmaster.com/member/addfavs?tm_link=tm_homeA_mytm_signin");
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
        req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
        }
```

Can anyone make sense of this?  I'm guessing it has something to do with the encryption between my machine and ticketmaster.com?  I get the following information from the tunnels when using Fiddler on the first code block:

ticketmaster.co.nz

> Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list. Secure Protocol: Tls12 Cipher: Aes256 256bits Hash Algorithm: Sha384 ?bits Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits == Server Certificate ========== [Subject] CN=www.ticketmaster.com.au, OU=Web Systems, O=Ticketmaster LLC, L=West Hollywood, S=California, C=US [Issuer] CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US [Serial Number] 1037AE6FF18FC34C953E39A6DFAB61B5 [Not Before] 5/31/2016 8:00:00 PM [Not After] 7/31/2017 7:59:59 PM [Thumbprint] FC3B52348FE320B9CAF441E98A8D7BFE1D7D3189 [SubjectAltNames] www.ticketmaster.co.nz, ticketmaster.co.nz, ticketmaster.com.au, www.ticketmaster.com.au

ticketmaster.com

> Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list. Secure Protocol: Tls12 Cipher: Aes256 256bits Hash Algorithm: Sha384 ?bits Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits == Server Certificate ========== [Subject] CN=www.ticketmaster.com, OU=Web Systems, O=Ticketmaster, L=West Hollywood, S=California, C=US [Issuer] CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US [Serial Number] 009C483B9154EE1160A8FEC2044DC8C5 [Not Before] 8/2/2016 8:00:00 PM [Not After] 8/3/2017 7:59:59 PM [Thumbprint] 488B2EE898E409484F61B1DD97023D4EE615C2EF [SubjectAltNames] www.ticketmaster.com, ticketmaster.com

I'm using .NET version 4.6.1 for this by the way.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? .NET 4 and earlier only supported TLS 1 - I wonder if it's possible that Fiddler is accepting a TLS 1 connection from your program, then forwarding the request using TLS 1.2 to TicketMaster?

Comment: This is likely environment-specific problem and not code related (i.e. firewalls, proxies,...) - code as shown works fine. I'd recommend trying other sites (starting with non-HTTPS) to narrow down problem.

Comment: @ Jon Davies Added it to the question

ver 4.6.1

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov

Did you actually run the code on your own machine to success?  I have recently switched machines so I thought it might be that, but I just tried the machine I used to build my apps on, and it doesn't work there either.  

I have no problem accessing ticketmaster.com via my chrome browser.  However, if I go to https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

or

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

ticketmaster.co.nz seems to work fine
ticketmaster.com fails on both those sites as well